# How is Geo Redundant Storage charged on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

SO I have been using the azure 3 month trial, to test out whether I want to use Microsoft Azure to host a project I am working on, however I have been very confused as I have run out of "Geo Redundant Storage" in the first month and I don't really understand why.

I have read this: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/ and the only thing I can make of it, is that it takes an average of how much storage you are using across a month, eg as long as I am using less then 35gb (for a 35gb limit) on average of storage space I am in the clear.

So under my Azure Subscriptsions 'STORAGE (GB/MONTH) - GEO REDUNDANT' it says '101.027% of 35 GB/month' (so I have reached my cap).

But I don't understand why this would be happening, all I have is a simple server with a nodejs web application and a redis database (pretty much an empty at the moment), all running on an ubuntu VM, and as I can't login and check storage now because it is disabled, but I am pretty sure it is nowhere ***even near*** 35gb total storage and never has been?

I am hoping someone can explain how the azure storage is charged or if I have missed something silly?

**Edit:** It just hit me that it could be redis, doing crazy things with IO? not sure if this is possible, but if it is, would I be better to use locally redundant storage and pay for locally redundant storage transactions?

**Edit 2:** On my graph it says I had been using 1.96gb / day. So that means its not the total harddrive space per month, is it harddrive space / day? (using 2gbs of data probably sounds about right with the OS included, if this is the case, that means they give you less then 2gb space on the trial, seems minute??)

[image: Azure Disk Usage Chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This caused due to the limitation on the geo redundant storage I have faced the same issue to fix this just disable geo redundant storage from the Windows Azure preview portal.

1. Open the Windows Azure preview portal.
2. Select Storage left.
3. The select your storage.
4. Click Configure on the top.
5. Turn off geo-replication.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Yeh, I found it was actually an old geo-redundant drive i mounted and forgot about, I removed the VM but the geo-redundant drive was still there hiding away.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by the image of your Ubuntum VM. If you read the pricing details (the link in your question) you'll see this:

> Compute hours do not include any Windows Azure Storage costs
>   associated with the image running in Windows Azure Virtual Machines. These costs are billed separately.

How large was the VM you created?

Comment: I used the Ubuntu Image offered already in azure (didn't upload my own).

Comment: You OS disk and additional data disks are persisted as page blobs in your storage account, this means they take part in the total amount of storage GB you used in your subscription.

Comment: So is it possible that my OS + Mounted disk simply add upto more then 35gb? (even if most of my mounted disk is empty?)